# Session expired in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a payment page that using the session of the member data. On one server it works without any problem, but on production (other server) I am thrown out of the page without credit transfer, after debbuging it I saw that I was thrown because the session of the member data expired (the member data is empty). Why did it happen on one server and not the other? The timout, setting, permissions are the same! How can I save the session for longer?

Comment: On production are there more than one servers to run the application?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya no